# How can I read files in system directory on a rooted device using NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have been trying to read system files in a NDK library, files like:

```
/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
//MainActivity.java:
private native String getNetworkList();

if(RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {
    String jsonList = getNetworkList();
    Log.d("TAG", "jsonList=" + jsonList);
}
```

and jni methods in ndk library:

```
//getNetworkList()
string name = "/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf"
string command = "su -c \"chmod 0777 ";
command += name;
command += "\"";
LogE("command=%s\n", command.c_str());

int exitCode = system(command.c_str());
LogE("exitCode=%d\n", exitCode);

//chmod success, exitCode=0

FILE *pFile = fopen(name, "r");
if (!pFile)
{
    LogE("fopen() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return false;
}
```

fopen() getting a permission denied error.

how should I do?
Thank you

Comment: The NDK does not give you any exception to the security model.  You will have to use your `su` root shim (or whatever it is that makes your device "rooted") to launch a helper application (perhaps `cat`) as root to do the reading for you.  This has been covered here many times before, so you should expect your question to probably be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it turns out that "su" is running in a new process, thus fopen() which running in the original process still have no root permission.

so I use the following code and it works fine:

```
FILE *pCmd = NULL;
char strCmd[1024] = "su -c \"cat ";
strcat(strCmd, file_name);
strcat(strCmd, "\"");

//use popen to read shell output
pCmd = popen(strCmd, "r");
if(!pCmd)
{
    LogE("popen() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return false;
}

//here you can read pCmd using fread, fgets, fgetc:
char token = fgetc(pCmd);

//when finish reading
pclose(pCmd);
```